# How can I write to a text file using Oracle?

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, text-files

I have a select query in Oracle. I want to write query results in a txt file with CRLF (end of line) char. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the utl_file package.
Code fragment:

```
l_output        utl_file.file_type;
l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w' );
utl_file.put(l_output, 'Hello' );
...
utl_file.new_line( l_output );
utl_file.fflush( l_output );
utl_file.fclose( l_output );
```

First of all create a directory object (the p_dir parameter of the fopen) and grant it read and write privileges.
See also at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple solutions:

- Use Oracle [utl_file](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) package
- Throught [sqlplus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm) with [spool](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm#sthref3036) and [attribute](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12008.htm#i2696913)